# Newbie Q about Scrapy pipeline.py

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am studying the Scrapy tutorial. To test the process I created a new project with these files:

[See my post in Scrapy group for links to scripts, I cannot post more than 1 link here.](http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/browse_frm/thread/4d52fa8c589a412a)

The spider runs well and scrapes the text between title tags and puts it in FirmItem

```
[whitecase.com] INFO: Passed FirmItem(title=[u'White &amp; Case LLP - Lawyers - Rachel B. Wagner '])
```

But I am stuck in the pipeline process. I want to add this FirmItem into a csv file so that I can add it to the database.

I am new to python and I am learning as I go along. I would appreciate if someone gave me a clue about how to make the pipelines.py work so that the scraped data is put into items.csv.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think they address your specific question in the [Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-data-using-an-item-pipeline).

It suggest, as others have here using the CSV module. Place the following in your `pipelines.py` file.

```
import csv

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'wb'))

    def process_item(self, domain, item):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['title'][0], item['link'][0], item['desc'][0]])
        return item
```

> Don’t forget to enable the pipeline by adding it to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting in your settings.py, like this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['dmoz.pipelines.CsvWriterPipeline']
```

Adjust to suit the specifics of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [CSV feed export](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) (available in v0.10) together with the [CsvItemExporter](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [module for reading/writing CSV files](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/library/csv.html), this is safer than writing the output yourself (and getting all quoting/escaping right...)

```
import csv
csvfile = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'w'))
csvfile.writerow([ firmitem.title, firmitem.url ])
csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know where FirmItem is. That's why I was trying to use the pipeline.py.
(Sorry, I am putting 4 spaces before lines but it's not formating properly)

    >>> csvfile = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'w'))

    >>> csvfile.writerow([ firmitem.title, firmitem.url])

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    csvfile.writerow([ firmitem.title, firmitem.url])

    NameError: name 'firmitem' is not defined

Comment: `firmitem` is your object with data

Comment: I am sorry, this is what I don't understand. How do I get FirmItem (I assume it should match the [class name](http://dpaste.org/fiSg/)?) When I run the code in IDLE I get "NameError: name 'FirmItem' is not defined"

Comment: No FirmItem is the class name. The variable name isn't printed in the line you showed in your question. But I think leeo has the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Open file and write to it.

```
f = open('my.cvs','w')
f.write('h1\th2\th3\n')
f.write(my_class.v1+'\t'+my_class.v2+'\t'+my_class.v3+'\n')
f.close()
```

Or output your results on stdout and then redirect stdout to file `./my_script.py >> res.txt`

Comment: This didn't work for me:

    >>> f = open('my.csv', 'rw')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    f = open('my.csv', 'rw')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rw') or filename: 'my.csv'